# Product Model Display Key Null Pointer

Tags: guidewire

When attempting to connect to either local or SQL DB I get the below error upon starting my server. Because it is calling at OOTB class I havent been able to debug.

```
    lnar-5cg84268sc          2020-01-21 15:07:38,381 ERROR Server.RunLevel ***** PolicyCenter unable to start *****
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at gw.api.productmodel.ProductModelDisplayKey.getPath(ProductModelDisplayKey.java:41)
        at com.guidewire.pc.api.productmodel.ProductModelObjectBase.verifyDisplayKeyNotEmpty(ProductModelObjectBase.java:647)
        at com.guidewire.pc.api.productmodel.ProductModelObjectBase.verifyFields(ProductModelObjectBase.java:587)
        at com.guidewire.pc.api.productmodel.AuditSchedulePatternInternal.verifyFields(AuditSchedulePatternInternal.java:187)
        at com.guidewire.pc.api.productmodel.ProductModelObjectBase.verify(ProductModelObjectBase.java:523)
        at com.guidewire.pc.domain.productmodel.impl.ProductModelImpl.verifyProductModel(ProductModelImpl.java:1685)
        at com.guidewire.pc.domain.productmodel.impl.ProductModelImpl.verifyProductModel(ProductModelImpl.java:1640)
        at com.guidewire.pc.domain.productmodel.impl.ProductModelImpl.verifyProductModelIfNeeded(ProductModelImpl.java:336)
        at com.guidewire.pc.domain.productmodel.impl.ProductModelImpl.lambda$activateVerifyAndLockPatternsIfNeeded$0(ProductModelImpl.java:322)
        at com.guidewire.pc.domain.productmodel.impl.ProductModelImpl$$Lambda$325/406648867.accept(Unknown Source)
        at com.guidewire.pc.domain.productmodel.impl.ProductModelImpl.lambda$runWithinTransaction$4(ProductModelImpl.java:2099)
        at com.guidewire.pc.domain.productmodel.impl.ProductModelImpl$$Lambda$326/1957698296.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.guidewire.pl.system.transaction.BootstrapTransaction.run(BootstrapTransaction.java:44)
        at com.guidewire.pl.system.transaction.TransactionManagerImpl.execute(TransactionManagerImpl.java:109)
        at com.guidewire.pc.domain.productmodel.impl.ProductModelImpl.runWithinTransaction(ProductModelImpl.java:2098)
        at com.guidewire.pc.domain.productmodel.impl.ProductModelImpl.activateVerifyAndLockPatternsIfNeeded(ProductModelImpl.java:316)
        at com.guidewire.pc.domain.productmodel.impl.ProductModelImpl.start(ProductModelImpl.java:237)
        at com.guidewire.pl.system.server.InitTab.startDependency(InitTab.java:465)
        at com.guidewire.pc.system.server.PCInitTab.applicationEnterNoDaemons(PCInitTab.java:58)
        at com.guidewire.pl.system.server.InitTab.enterNoDaemons(InitTab.java:875)
        at com.guidewire.pl.system.server.InitTab.increaseRunLevelTo(InitTab.java:650)
        at com.guidewire.pl.system.server.InitTab.setRunLevel(InitTab.java:380)
        at com.guidewire.pl.system.servlet.GuidewireStartupServlet.init(GuidewireStartupServlet.java:88)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:349)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:812)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1322)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:732)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:490)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:342)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:290)
        at com.guidewire.commons.jetty.GWServerJettyServerMain$JettyServer.doStart(GWServerJettyServerMain.java:83)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1250)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1174)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:509)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:651)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:99)
        at com.guidewire.commons.jetty.GWServerJettyServerMain.main(GWServerJettyServerMain.java:69)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error might be you are deleted existing OOTB Display key, go to Local History and revert all changes try to restart the PC or see the same changes git and revert back all changes try to start the machine.